# How do you call a method for an Objective-C object's superclass from elsewhere?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, overriding, superclass

If you're implementing a subclass, you can, within your implementation, explicitly call the superclass's method, even if you've overridden that method, i.e.:

```
[self overriddenMethod]; //calls the subclass's method
[super overriddenMethod]; //calls the superclass's method
```

What if you want to call the superclass's method from somewhere outside the subclass's implementation, i.e.:

```
[[object super] overriddenMethod]; //crashes
```

Is this even possible? And by extension, is it possible to go up more than one level within the implementation, i.e.:

```
[[super super] overriddenMethod]; //will this work?
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

A more pleasant option (for debugging) is to add a category method which does it for you:

```
- (void) callSuperMethod { [super overriddenMethod]; }
```

The fact that there’s no more convenient way to do this is very much by design.

Answer (score 14):

You can send `[[[object class] superclass] methodForSelector: ...]` and invoke through the IMP pointer directly, if you want... but if you're doing this, there's probably something very wrong with your application's design.

Comment: Not design. Need this for debugging.