# Get super class instance in Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

How can I get super class instance?

```
id superObject=super;
```

Xcode says, "Use of undeclared identifier super"

Comment: why you need your super object?

Comment: I want to add a target with a method implemented in super class.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Objective-C: preferred way to retrieve the superclass of a Class instance](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7141505/objective-c-preferred-way-to-retrieve-the-superclass-of-a-class-instance)

Comment: The link that you have posted returns "Class". I am looking for the object.

Comment: @andyPaul, Rajesh's answer seems to be correct. Your child class inherits all the methods of your `super`, why do not you just use `self` to use your super's methods?

Comment: @NeilGaliaskarov I agree with Rajesh's points in accessing the properties and methods of super clas. But, Can we conclude there is no way one can get "object" of super class in Objective C, whereas in Java it is possible?

Comment: @andyPaul the point here is you don't need it, because you can access it directly from your subclass.

Comment: hope,this link helpful to get super class instace

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2877251/how-do-you-call-a-method-for-an-objective-c-objects-superclass-from-elsewhere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not completely clear to me what you are trying to do, but based partly on your comments to your own question here is a guess.

It seems you may be confused over `super` in both Objective-C and Java. Both these languages are based on inheritance where a subclass instance is also an instance of its superclass. In neither language is there the concept of a "superclass instance/object". The meaning of `super` in the two languages is essentially the same, but differs in detail due to the different way the two languages support hiding.

In Objective-C `super` is a *keyword* while `self`, which references the instance a method was called on, is a *variable* (and the equivalent of Java's `this`). The `super` keyword is used to call a method on `self` but to start the search for the implementation to call in the superclass instead of the current class. It is usually used by an overriding method to call the method it has overridden.

However in your comments you also write:

> I want to add a target with a method implemented in super class

which suggests you are trying to use an API which uses the target/action pattern, e.g. `NSControl` and others.

If the method you wish to call is not overridden in the current class then simply passing `self` as the target will invoke the superclass method. For example:

```
@interface Base : NSObject

- (IBAction) actionOne:(id) sender;
- (IBAction) actionTwo:(id) sender;

@end

@interface Child : Base
...
@end

@implementation Child

- (void) setActionFor:(NSControl *)aControl
{
   aControl.target = self;
   aControl.action = @selector(actionOne:); // actionOne is NOT overridden in Child
}
...
```

However if your subclass overrides a superclass method and you wish to set the superclass implementation as the action then you must write a method in your subclass which invokes the superclass method. For example, expanding on the previous example and passing `Base`'s `actionTwo` as an action in a `Child` method when `Child` overrides `actionTwo`:

```
@implementation Child

// override Base method
- (IBAction) actionTwo:(id)sender { ... }

// provide a way to directly invoke Base method bypassing override
- (IBAction) superActionTwo:(id)sender
{
   [super actionTwo:sender];
}

- (void) setActionFor:(NSControl *)aControl
{
   aControl.target = self;
   aControl.action = @selector(superActionTwo:); // indirectly set Base's actionTwo 
}
```

HTH

Answer (score 0):

Your **self** in-turn consist your **super**. You can access your super properties through self.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a separate object that represents your "super" object. Self is an instance of your class, which is part of a class hierarchy. When you call a method using the super keyword, you're specifying that you want to use your super class's implementation of that method. If your subclass doesn't override a method defined in super, then performing the selector on self will trigger a miss on your class's method lookup table and find the method definition on your superclass.

So, the simple answer is you should be able to accomplish what you're trying to do through self =]

Answer (score 0):

Here you are trying initialize object with a class, not with instance of this class.

May be something like this?

`id instance = [super init];`